# Calling DLL from another namespace

Tags: c#, dll, namespaces

I like to connect a library DLL with my existing c# main code.

The main looks like:

```
using GanttC;
namespace WindowsApp
{
   public partial class Form4 : Form
   {
       var instance = new GanttC.Example();
       instance.Example();
                                              or simply 
       GanttC.Example();

    }
}
```

How can I use the following DLL ..?

```
namespace GanttC
{
   public partial class Example : Form
   {
        ProjectManager _mProject;
        public Example()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
           _mProject = new ProjectManager();
           _mProject.Add(new Task() { Name = "New Task" });
           _mChart.Init(_mProject);
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You should add reference to dll in main project.

Comment: [how to add a reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Comment: darson, I added the reference already.My understanding was that you need to declare an instance of the class that contains the function <namespace.classname YourClass = new namespace.classname();> then you use the function as follows <YourClass.functionname();>

Comment: @joe tip: use `` if you want to mark pieces of code in your comments `like this ` instead of <like this>

Comment: what function are you trying to call? you only got a constructor in the `Example` class...

Comment: Also, why are you manually calling the constructor (`public Example()`) again after creating an instance? That won't work, is there some part of your code you are not showing?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's clear this up...

Your "example" doesn't contain any other methods, so it's not a great example. Let's pretend there's another method called 'Test' like so

```
namespace GanttC
{
   public partial class Example : Form
   {
        ProjectManager _mProject;
        public Example()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
           _mProject = new ProjectManager();
           _mProject.Add(new Task() { Name = "New Task" });
           _mChart.Init(_mProject);
        }

        public int Test()
        {
            return 2 + 2;
        }
    }
}
```

You had the right idea: after referencing the library you have to create an instance. In your case the class is called `Example` so to create an instance of that you call the constructor (also called `Example`). After that you can access instance methods from your newly created object.

```
using GanttC;
namespace WindowsApp
{
   public partial class Form4 : Form
   {
       var instance = new GanttC.Example();
       var result = instance.Test();
   }
}
```

Comment: DrewJordan, became clear now. I missed the difference between constructor and method in this case. Many thanks.